# Looking for a sample program to test Stata/MP

Tags: stata

I recently purchase a Stata MP12(8 cores) license running on a Linux server.

Does anyone has written a Stata programme, say a simulation study to test the performance of Stata MP? I would like to monitor the number of cores and memory actually being used during the processing of the job.

I would be grateful if someone could share the programme with us.

Thank you for your help

Comment: why does this have "SAS" and "R" tags ... ????

Comment: Because SAS and R users might also use Stata

Comment: To Josh O'Brien- I disagree that you removed SAS and R tags

Comment: @Tony Tags should describe the question, not possible responses, related fields, or the intended audience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm think we need more detail on what you want to compare.  If you just want to see how long a job involving large data and intense data routines takes in Stata 12 versus, say, Stata 11, then you can run any parallelized command and set your timer (or rmsg) on. If you want to compare parallelized vs. non-parallelized commands in Stata 12 MP on big data, then you could do the same with commands like -logit- (parallelized) versus -xtmixed- (not).  Finally, take a look at this report about MP performance with various commands:

http://www.stata.com/statamp/statamp.pdf

You could run something like this and monitor your memory/cores, but it would be more helpful if we knew what you wanted to compare/observe:

```
clear*
set rmsg on
set obs 10000000
forval n = 1/5 {
g i`n' = runiform()
}
g dv = rbinomial(1,.3)
memory

qui logit dv i*

qui xtmixed dv i*

*with bootstrap:
qui bs, reps(2000): logit dv i*
```